# Rearranging an equation (2)

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

How would you rearrange this equation to make *U* the subject?

$$f_2=\frac{Vf_1}{V+U}$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

$$f_2 = \frac{Vf_1}{V+U}$$
$$\frac 1 {f_2} = \frac{V+U}{Vf_1}$$
$$\frac {Vf_1} {f_2} = V+U$$
$$\frac {Vf_1} {f_2} -V = U$$
$$\left( \frac {f_1} {f_2} -1 \right) V = U$$

Answer (score 0):

The equation is:
$$f_2 = \frac{V f_1}{V + U}$$

And the goal is solve for U.
First, raise both sides of the equation to the power of -1, like so:

$$\frac 1 {f_2} = \frac{V+U}{Vf_1}$$

Then, get rid of the $Vf_1$.

$$\frac {Vf_1} {f_2} = V+U$$
Now, just subtract V, and you have solved the problem.
$$\frac {Vf_1} {f_2} -V = U$$